# Basic question on stone-cech compactification

Tags: general-topology

Let $\widetilde{X}$ be a compactification of a space $X$.

This implies that $\widetilde{X}$ is compact together with an embedding $e : X \rightarrow \widetilde{X}$ such that $e(X)$ is dense in $\widetilde{X}$.

Let $X' = e(X)$

Now $X$ is homeomorphic to $e(X)$ and we have that  $\widetilde{X}$ = $\bar X^{'} $  i.e closure of $X'$ is $\widetilde{X}$.

But I have seen that at various places, it has been written that $\bar X = \widetilde{X}$(by identifying $X$ with $X'$.

Now using this if $B((0,1])$ is stone-cech compactification of $(0,1]$ then $Cl((0,1])$ = $[0,1]$ should be equal to $B((0,1])$.

What is wrong in this?

I am definitely overlooking something. Please help!

Comment: Check what the definition of 'closure' is.

Answer (score 1):

The homeomorphism class of the closure is not a topological invariant: specifically, it is not true that for any two embeddings $f:(A,\tau)\hookrightarrow (B,\sigma)$ and $g:(A,\tau)\hookrightarrow (C,\rho)$ there is a homeomorphism $u:\operatorname{cl}_B{f[A]}\to \operatorname{cl}_C{g[A]}$.

Even if you add the condition that $B$ and $C$ should be compact Hausdorff, this fact does not change.

Comment: For a simple example of this, $(0,1)$ embeds as a dense subset of the compact Hausdorff spaces $[0,1]$ and $S^1$, which are not homeomorphic.